# flutter error - The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

I want to put chart in my card, the sample code of chart is just used which link is https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/points.

and the below code is my code.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 0),
  child: Card(
         elevation: 0.333,
         child: HistoryChart, <--- I want to put chart here
  )
)
```

But I got The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' error.

What should I change to do work this code properly?

Comment: Add `()` after `HistoryChart` like this `child: HistoryChart(),`

Comment: @JideGuru then new error as 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing

Comment: You need to add the missing argument for the widget

Comment: @DanielLee Can you show us the code for HistoryChart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After import **PointsLineChart** class from [line_charts](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/points) package

You put the **Type** in place of the **Widget**

If you want to show simple data in the chart, try this:

```
   Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 0),
    child: Card(
      elevation: 0.333,
      child: Container(
        child: PointsLineChart.withSampleData(),
        height: 250,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

if you want real data, try this:

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0.333,
        child: Container(height: 250,
          child: PointsLineChart(
            getData(),
            // Disable animations for image tests.
            animate: false,
          ),
        ),
      )));



List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> getData() {
final data = [
  new LinearSales(0, 5),
  new LinearSales(1, 25),
  new LinearSales(2, 100),
  new LinearSales(3, 75),
];

return [
  new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
    id: 'Sales',
    colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
    domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
    measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
    data: data,
  )
];}
```